# Can I travel to Boston from Bangalore with layover at London?

Tags: usa, air-travel, london, covid-19, bangalore

I'm going to Boston on an F1 visa from Bangalore. Because of the ongoing COVID restrictions, is it allowed to travel to US if i have a layover at London airport?

Comment: Is your itinerary non-stop from Bangalore to London? Which London airport? What airline(s)?

Comment: Its non stop from Bangalore to London's Hethrow airport and then non-stop from London to USA. British airways is the airline

Comment: Please check with the airline though. I know Turkish Airlines has cancelled all its flights to UK, Netherlands, South Africa and Denmark. Flight suspension in the UK comes, I am assuming, as an effect of a mutated strain of virus found there.

Comment: Yes. These rules are so unpredictable and whats worse is they dont even honour the tickets already booked.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> USA:

> students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents [are allowed] if they arrive from or have been in Ireland (Rep.), United Kingdom or Schengen Member States in the past 14 days.

Comment: Does that mean the OP must "enter" the UK? IOW, does the exception apply if the OP merely transits in the UK and doesn't pass UK immigration and customs?